# How to route message to Service bus queue using routing query?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an IoT hub with connected devices which sends telemetry messages. I want to read messages from each device separately, so I decided to create a different endpoint for each device. For sorting messages I use routes with query, but when I add a query rule to the route, messages stop going to the endpoint. Connected device uses MQTT.

Screenshots are below:

- [Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmyyB.png)
- [Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at4D2.png)
- [toMyEndpoint route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1llU.png)

Comment: Hi Openzz, the answers solves your issue? Any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your query expression is correct.

But make sure you set content type and content encoding like this:

```
Message eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"boarded\":\"0\"}"));
eventMessage.ContentType = "application/json";
eventMessage.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to send a D2C message on the following topic:

```
devices/{yourDeviceId}/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

Note, that the content-encoding is **utf-8**.